# Can't get Media Query to work properly for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I am trying to use media queries to affix text to the bottom of a background image on a second page. When I edit the padding-top it affects the content on desktop mode, even if I adjust the media query to (max-width: 500px) and keep the desktop above 500px (which should then be outside the parameters of the media query, right?), but it has no bearing on mobile views. This is what I think the code should be, and it looks fine on desktop but leaves a large gap on mobile.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {}
.site-boxed-container .site-content {
max-width: 100%;
padding-top: 50%;
}
```

I also tried adding the following code to force mobile to have no top padding, but again it had no effect on mobile:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 499px)
.site-boxed-container .site-content{
    padding-top: 0%;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Click to edit your post, after, click on the brackets to add code { }

Comment: Could you check the CSS you have posted as it isn't correct syntax. Your browser should be giving an error if you do an inspect in its dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the snippets of code you have shown are legal CSS.

The first:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {}
.site-boxed-container .site-content {
max-width: 100%;
padding-top: 50%;
}
```

does nothing. You have given the media query nothing to do - there is a matched pair of curly brackets immediately after the query. So everything will have the same padding-top.

The second:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 499px)
.site-boxed-container .site-content{
    padding-top: 0%;
}
```

has a syntax error, there is no opening curly bracket immediately after the media query. Everything that pertains to a media query must come within curly brackets.

The correct syntax for this would be:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 499px) {
  .site-boxed-container .site-content{
     padding-top: 0%;
   }
}
```

assuming you want to make padding top zero for viewports with widths between 250px and 499px.